# How to select columns using a conditional operator (>)?

Tags: r, database, select

I am trying to select columns titled 'X1995' till 'X2020', I intend to use the conditional operator to make the selection by selecting columns that are above 'X1994'.

```
library(readr)
dat <- read.csv("per_capita.csv")
head(dat)
a <- dat$X1994[dat$Country.Name == "India"]
a
format(a, scientific = F, big.mark = ',')
b <- dat$1994>[dat$Country.Name == "India"]
b
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all columns except 'Country.Name' have prefix 'X' followed by 4 digit year, `filter` the rows where Country.Name' is 'India' and `select` after converting the column names to numeric by extracting the numeric part and use `>`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    filter(Country.Name == "India") %>%
    select(names(.)[-1][readr::parse_number(names(.)[-1]) > 1994])
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! However, are you selecting columns with- 
select(names(.) [-1])?

Comment: @KetanMehta yes, as your post doesn't have much info about the columns in the data. `[-1]` implies it is selecting all columns other than Country.Name which I assume as first column

Comment: I tried the code and its giving me an error in the last line.